# Semicolon separated aliases seems to break argument references (tcsh)

Tags: tcsh

I create two aliases as follows:

```
alias echo1 'echo \!#:1';  - Echo first argument

alias echo2 'echo \!#:2';  - Echo second argument
```

then `echo1 foo fee` -> `foo`

and `echo2 foo fee` -> `fee`

however,

```
echo1 fee; echo2 fuu fii; -> fee (only)
```

while,

```
echo2 fuu fii; echo1 fee; -> fii, fii
```

It appears that when aliases are put on a single line, separated by a semicolon, the arguments for the second command come from the output of the first command, rather than using the second set of arguments.  That seems counter-intuitive to me.  I would expect two commands separated by a semicolon to produce the same result as if they were issued on separate lines, but this is apparently not the case.  Seems like there is an implied pipe.  Does anyone know why?

This same behavior occurs when defining a single alias with two comma separated commands.  I can't figure out how to make each command index the arguments that follow it.

Comment: "*on a single line, separated by a comma*" -- I think you mean semicolon `;`, not comma `,`.

Comment: I don't think there's an implied pipe. I think the `\!#:2` is expanding to something on the line rather than in the command. I don't have an explanation (other than that csh/tcsh syntax is ugly and poorly defined).

Comment: [Csh programming considered harmful](https://www-uxsup.csx.cam.ac.uk/misc/csh.html).